# Python Module import 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

Hey I have a tree structure with an empty **init**.py in each directory/subdirectory. However, I get a failed to load module Utilities from my Home directory .py file.

Using python 3.7

My tree looks like the following:

```
    C:.
├───Tests
│   ├───Checkout
│   ├───GlobalFooter
│   ├───GlobalHeader
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───Home
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───MyAccount
│   ├───ProductDetail
│   ├───ProductResults
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   └───SignIn
└───Utilities
    └───__pycache__
```

I have tried the following:

```
sys.path.insert(0, 'C:/Web2/TSC.WebFactory.Web2.Tests/Utilities')
from Utilities.utils import addCookies, configureOptions
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to access your whole tree of modules by their package qualified names, you shouldn't include `Utilities` in the `sys.path` entry; `from Utilities.utils import ...` assumes that some folder in `sys.path` has a package/folder named `Utilities`, that contains either a subpackage/folder named `utils` or a submodule/file named `utils.py`; by adding `'C:/Web2/TSC.WebFactory.Web2.Tests/Utilities'` to `sys.path`, it expects `'C:/Web2/TSC.WebFactory.Web2.Tests/Utilities/Utilities/utils.py'` (note doubled `Utilities`).

The solution here is to remove that final directory from the path:

```
sys.path.insert(0, 'C:/Web2/TSC.WebFactory.Web2.Tests')
```

Now `from Utilities.utils import ...` will look in `C:\Web2\TSC.WebFactory.Web2.Tests` for `Utilities\utils.py` and find it as expected.

Side-note: If you want to keep to Windows standard backslashes as directory separators, you can use them fairly cleanly by just making the path a raw string literal, avoiding the need for constant escaping:

```
sys.path.insert(0, r'C:\Web2\TSC.WebFactory.Web2.Tests')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already tried, do this as when doing sys.path.insert you shouldn't have to specify the folder on the import line.

`from utils import addCookies, configureOptions`